# Differences Between Azure Search in Commercial vs. Azure Government

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Does Azure Search have feature parity between what is available in the commercial cloud vs. what is available in Azure Government?  If not, do we have any pointers to what the differences are?

Comment: Take a look at this document -https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-services-aiandcognitiveservices - This article outlines variations and considerations when using Cognitive Services and the Azure Bot Service in the Azure Government environment.

This doc -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/ ( Under the 'Reference' Sub-section> 'Services' )  -Lists all the supported service comparison.

Comment: You can also post a feedback (PR) on the respective Azure docs ( I have shared above) for a feature comparison list on Azure Search. I will also share feedback on this internally. 
Azure Updates: https://azure.microsoft.com/updates/azure-search-is-now-integrated-with-the-azure-government-cloud/